# List of available marker symbols

Tags: geojson, mapbox, markers

I would like to use marker symbols for markers on my Mapbox (v3.0.1) map, I have found several sources that say I can use icons from [this page](https://www.mapbox.com/maki-icons/). Yes, some of them work for me (danger, religious-christian), but some of them do not, for example gaming or toilet.

Does anybody know the real available list of marker-symbols?

Answer (score 7):

On https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/v3/static/ *[ EDIT (Aug 20, '19): this page currently doesn't exist anymore, an archived version can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150907064418/https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/v3/static/ ]* you can find the following list of icons that can be used. Your examples match that list.

- a-z
- 0-9
- aerialway
- airfield
- airport
- alcohol-shop
- america-football
- art-gallery
- bakery
- bank
- bar
- baseball
- basketball
- beer
- bicycle
- building
- bus
- cafe
- camera
- campsite
- car
- cemetery
- chemist
- cinema
- circle-stroked
- circle
- city
- clothing-store
- college
- commercial
- cricket
- cross
- dam
- danger
- dentist
- disability
- dog-park
- embassy
- emergency-telephone
- entrance
- farm
- fast-food
- ferry
- fire-station
- fuel
- garden
- gift
- golf
- grocery
- hairdresser
- harbor
- heart
- heliport
- hospital
- ice-cream
- industrial
- land-use
- laundry
- library
- lighthouse
- lodging
- logging
- london-underground
- marker-stroked
- marker
- minefield
- mobilephone
- monument
- museum
- music
- oil-well
- park2
- park
- parking-garage
- parking
- pharmacy
- pitch
- place-of-worship
- playground
- police
- polling-place
- post
- prison
- rail-above
- rail-light
- rail-metro
- rail-underground
- rail
- religious-christian
- religious-jewish
- religious-muslim
- restaurant
- roadblock
- rocket
- school
- scooter
- shop
- skiing
- slaughterhouse
- soccer
- square-stroked
- square
- star-stroked
- star
- suitcase
- swimming
- telephone
- tennis
- theatre
- toilets
- town-hall
- town
- triangle-stroked
- triangle
- village
- warehouse
- waste-basket
- water
- wetland
- zoo

Recently I made a visual list of these: https://map.michelstuyts.be/icons/

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox icons can also be found here: https://www.mapbox.com/maki-icons/